# Kendo UI - Filter Resources in Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to dynamically filter resources in `Scheduler` and show resource and events based on the filter. Please see below [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lilan123/UPuDE/6) project which I created.

As per my requirement I want to show only attendees: 1 and his event in `Scheduler` when I clicked on filter button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not applying the filtering on the datasource correctly.

Try this line

```
schedulerTimeLine.dataSource.filter(filter);
```

instead of this one:

```
schedulerTimeLine.resources[0].dataSource.filter(filter);
```

**Update:**

After clearing up your requirements i think what you need is already present in your demo. You only need to put up proper attendee value in the filter to achieve the desired effect, i.e:

```
var filter = {
    logic: "or",
    filters:[
        {field:"value", operator:"eq",value:1}
    ]
};
```

This filter will display only attendee with id 1name Alex.

Comment: Well, If I apply this code schedulerTimeLine.dataSource.filter(filter); It will filter events for attendee and hide those events from scheduler and still attendee will be shown in the scheduler attendees list. what I want to hide is attendee from the scheduler and It will hide attendee events automatically from the scheduler .

Comment: In that case the line above should remain the same, and you should manually invoke refresh of the scheduler view: schedulerTimeLine.view(schedulerTimeLine.view().name);

Comment: I believe this is the same problem you are trying to solve: http://www.telerik.com/forums/add-filter-to-resource-datasource

Comment: Thanks all and actually it was sorted in demo project and now the problem is filtering is not functioning well for current week when the filter does not have records.